# Limit Access To mysql information_schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

In case of mysql attacks, many times user extracts information from information_schema.

can i do something in mysql that can restricts user to xtracts information from information_schema while all privileges on rest database is available.

Answer (score 2):

When you grant permission, you specify the database and table names that you're allowing access to. Don't give unprivileged users modification privileges to `*.*`, list the databases explicitly in the grants.

Comment: +1 Don't allow access to the mysql database for these users, either.